# Vote to delete warns that of other duplicates that aren't duplicates

Tags: bug, duplicate-questions, vote-to-delete

I was going to vote to delete [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/109997/how-do-you-protect-your-software-from-illegal-distribution). I clicked the delete button and confirmed it and then got:

> *"1 posts (10530917) have been closed as a duplicate of this one; continue anyway?"*

[10530917](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10530917/need-to-create-setup-file-in-java-but-with-license-key-that-is-write-protected) does indeed exist, but it was closed as "Not a real question". There's a comment linking to the first question on it, but nothing to suggest there's ever been a proposed of duplicate in the history or the visible comments.

What gives?

Comment: (I resisted the urge to complain about the plural/singular thing)

Comment: ...says the guy tied to a chair with Jeff brandishing a giant "S" over his head.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to guess that at least one of the close votes on `10530917` was as a duplicate of the question you were trying to close.

Bear in mind the close message is based on the **majority** but does not indicate a unanimous vote.

Comment: Should the message still appear for cases where there is no visible evidence of it being an exact duplicate?

Comment: I think so, but that's just me.  That probably should be it's own meta question.